# Is the a method to recover lost project?

Tags: windows

I used OneKey recover to restore my system, and I was surprised that my external drive was formatted, is there any chance to physicaly recover my data? Thanks

I tried different recovery(aomei, rstudio, winfrgui, recuva...) software without success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid your question is off-topic here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.